# Only one result showing in while loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to show all results from the database, but to show "None" if there are no results. However, when I run my code I only get a single result instead of the two that are currently there. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
$select1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `update` WHERE did='joined'");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($select1);
if ($num_rows==0) {
    $joined="None";
}else{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select1)) {
        $joined=$row['name'].", ";
    }
}
echo $joined;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are over writing the data you process in the while loop by using `$joined = $row['name'].", ";`

Instead concatenate all occurances onto the string using the `.=` operator

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select1)) {
    $joined .= $row['name'].", ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, now this is adding each result more than once, though. So I see user1, user2, user1, user2

Comment: use fetch_array instead of assoc.

Comment: I was able to work around it by using echo inside the while loop instead of holding it in a variable and echoing it later, but still unsure of why the variable wasn't working.